# create ipa without RoboVM in a project libgdx

Tags: java, ios, intellij-idea, build, libgdx

I am creating an application with libgdx , and I wish I could produce an IPA without using RoboVM , because since version 1.9 became a fee .
I saw on the original documentation that you can do with the gradlew.

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-on-the-Commandline#packaging-the-project

command:

```
gradlew ios:createIPA
```

but I saw that still requires robovm . you can create an IPA without robovm ? or if there is a plugin that makes the IPA.

RoboVM 1.8 download: http://download.robovm.org/robovm-1.8.0.tar.gz

I use Android studio (IntelliJ)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No IPA without robovm.

You can downgrade to robovm 1.8 or get a free license as any libGDX developer gets according to this: http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=3762

Why did you create this questions at 3 places over the internet :)

Comment: and he pulled three times my questions :) seriously, thanks response

Comment: Never knew Robovm was free for LibGDX users up to a team of 3 developers. Great news, thanks.

Comment: it recently became free..wasn't just a month ago